# Broken "String" into a variable in Python

Tags: python

I am new on Python so I need some help here.  After forming a string, I would like to split it in a variable.

I am trying this:

```
numero = str(input("Digite um numero de quatro digitos"));

y = len(numero) 

for i in range ( y): 

ai = numero [y]

^

error ....... invalid syntax
```

But I receive a "invalid syntax" a
point to a white space. I am using the black box, like "cmd" of Python, so I don't have many details, just that.

I forgot a e.g: The user inform 1234 , I need `ai` = [1,2,3,4] , cause after that I will manipulate.  I already tried the `split(" ")`, but it just returned one position into the array.

Comment: Please copy over the error again, but instead of the quote button click the code button instead. This preserves whitespace, and might help us figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [identation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) problem in for loop on `ai = numero [y]` line. Try this:

```
numero = str(input("Digite um numero de quatro digitos"));

y = len(numero)

for i in range (y):
    ai = numero [y]
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfkRz88U6S8) is a nice video about identation in python.

Comment: Why not `for i in numero: print i`?

Comment: You may ask this to the OP. The OP actually asked the reason for syntax error. So I mentioned it. :)

Answer (score 1):

> The body of the loop must be indented. indentation is Python’s way of
>   grouping statements.  Note that each line within a basic block must be
>   indented by the same amount.

so the corrected syntax is:

```
for i in range (y):
    ai = numero[i]
```

you can start learning python basics from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)